# Creating socket compatible with IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

I am writing a program which can read the IP address that I have been assigned on a specific network interface (VLAN: eth0.32). I won't know if I have been assigned an IPv4 or a IPv6 address so I try to write it protocol family agnostic.

The way it works is: with a for, I navigate through the list of available network interfaces and I stop at the point where I find my VLAN (eth0.32) to read the IP address. Anyways, at this point of development I just want that it works for IPv4 but leave it ready when I want to implement IPv6 support.

The program works and reads the IPv4 address if I create the socket normally:

```
sd=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

But as I won't be able to read IPv6 addresses with this socket family (PF_INET=IPv4) I do it like this:

```
sd=socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, IPV6_V6ONLY, 0, sizeof(int));
```

The problem is that with this IPv6 socket, it fails to accomplish the if condition to read the ip address:

```
if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) == 0)
```

For more information, this is my whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    struct ifconf ifc;
    struct ifreq ifr[MAX_NETWORK_INTERFACES];
    int ifc_num, addr, i;
    static uint8 sd=0;

    sd=socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, IPV6_V6ONLY, 0, sizeof(int)); //I change the socket option IPV6_V6ONLY to false, so it should be compatible with IPv4

    if (sd > 0)
    {
        ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(ifr);
        ifc.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf = (caddr_t)ifr; //Buffer address

        if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) == 0)
        {
            ifc_num = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq);  //Number of network interfaces found

            for (i = 0; i < ifc_num; i++)
            {

                if(ifr[i].ifr_addr.sa_family != AF_INET) //If it is not an IPv4 address, we do nothing
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (strcmp(ifr[i].ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name,"eth0.32")==0)
                {
                    if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr[i]) == 0) // HERE IS WHERE THE IPv6 SOCKET DOESN'T ENTER!!!
                    {
                        addr = ntohl(((struct sockaddr_in *)(&ifr[i].ifr_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr);

                    }

                    fclose(fp);

                    break;  // end loop
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return addr;

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: GetSocketForAddressForAdapter might help you - https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/networkutils/adapters.cpp#L111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `getifaddrs` not `ioctl SIOCGIFADDR`.

Comment: In that case, is `(ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) == 0)` also not working?

Comment: @Nacao, these IOCTls are not covered by any standard and are not portable. You must consult your OS documentation - or if asking a question on SO, tell us what OS you are using. On Linux use `rnetlink(7)`. On windows you probably want the "IP Helper" APIs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366071(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. I am using Linux. I have tested this code implementation only for IPv4 addresses and it works fine the problem described above comes when I want to add IPv6 support, it just doesn't work for IPv4 again.

Comment: @Nacao, Linux documentation says that SIOGIFCONF only returns IPv4 addresses. See http://linux.die.net/man/7/rtnetlink, http://linux.die.net/man/7/ipv6, http://linux.die.net/man/7/netdevice

Comment: You are right. I have read those and used `getifaddrs`. Now I have a list of network interfaces where I can navigate through with a for. I want it to print the ip address of my VLAN (eth0.32) by filtering them by name `if (strcmp(ifa->ifa_name,"eth0.32")==0)` and it does but it prints out the IPv4 address and the IPv6 address. 

That is strange since I only have IPv4 address established. By debugging it I realized that there is a network device with name "eth0.32" and family AF_INET but also another with the same name from AF_INET6. How is that possible?

Comment: @Nacao, an interface can have multiple addresses.